# Pandas is making an error while reading a column from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

So I have a google stock dataset that has a 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close' and 'Volume' columns. The problem is that pandas keeps saying that the 'Close' column is of type 'Object'.

I found the problem when I tried to scale that column using the `MinMaxScaler` and that's when I got this error: `could not convert string to float: '1,008.64'`

When I tried converting it to a float using the `astype('float')` function, I get the same error. When I try the `to_numeric(price['Close'], errors='coerce')` function, it just sets some rows as NULL.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

train_data = pd.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/Data LSTM TimeSeries/Google_Stock_Price.csv')

price = train_data[['Close']]
price.info()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
price['Close'] = scaler.fit_transform(price['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

price['Close'] = price['Close'].astype('float')
price['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(price['Close'], errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Maybe `price = train_data[['Close']]` should be `price = train_data['Close']`?

Comment: @Barmar when I tried that, I got a Series instead of a dataframe and when I tried to check it's dtype it still showed object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `thousands` argument when you use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to make sure that your values are read correctly with the `,` delimiter

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/Data LSTM TimeSeries/Google_Stock_Price.csv', thousands = ",")
```